# Get folder name from list of string

Tags: groovy

I have a list of a hundred folders like below:

```
C:\Mother\Son\foler_A\a_file.txt
C:\Mother\Son\foler_A\foler_B\a_file.txt
C:\Mother\Son\foler_B\a_file.txt
C:\Mother\Son\foler_C\foler_D\a_file.txt
...
```

Can someone help me to get the list of the lastest folder level like:

```
['folder_A', [folder_B], [folder_B],[folder_D]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these files actually exist on your system, you could do:

```
def parents = folders.collect { new File(it).parentFile?.name }
```

If not, you could do:

```
def parents = folders*.split( '\\\\' )*.getAt(-2)
```

Comment: sorry, if it is not the right place to ask. @tim_yates could you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/q/29635294/553060 ?